# Ist ein „deswegen“ vor „weil“ überflüssig?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, redundancy

Ich habe öfters Äußerungen folgender Art gehört:

> Es ist deswegen wichtig, weil ...

Soweit ich das verstehe, ist der Satz auch ohne *deswegen* nicht ungrammatisch. Meine Frage ist, ob *deswegen* im Beispiel oben überflüssig klingt oder dem Satz einfach einen anderen Sinn gibt (z. B. Betonung, Selbstbewusstsein)?

Comment: Aus meiner Sicht legt das *deswegen* eine besondere Betonung auf die Begründung. Der Satz ist jedoch auch ohne *deswegen* korrekt und vollständig.

Comment: Noch eine Steigerung: Es ist gerade deswegen wichtig, weil...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redundanz ist ein wichtiger Teil der Sprache und wird gern eingesetzt, um Dinge zu verstärken. Hier steht *deswegen* für *aus dem Grund* und betont für den Gegenüber, dass dieser Satz eine Begründung liefert. Man kann diesen Zusatz aber auch problemlos weglassen.